# Tabulate Intersection is not accurate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I'm new to ArcGIS, and I'm trying to find the percentage of the overlapped area between two class feature.

For this I'm using the tool *Tabulate intersection*. However, my values seem to be inaccurate after the tabulation process is completed.

The percentage nor the area match what I'm inputting into the tool. Also the percentages don't add up to a 100 when I have more than one item in the zone.

My units are in acres, and I don't know what might be causing this issue.

ArcMap V. 10.4.1

[image]

These are the class features that I'm trying to intersect. The colorful one is the zone feature and the purple is the class feature.

The purple layer has its area values on its attribute table and I thought that once I do the intersection and place these area values onto the class field I was going to get a percentage of these areas divided by the intersected zones, but I didn't getting that. What I got is shown on the first picture and it doesn't matter if I use the zone feature as the input class feature and vice versa. The area values don't match.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about these values? What exactly are you inputting when you use the tabulation tool? Perhaps a screenshot of the accompanying shapes might help as well.

Comment: I added a quick explanation and a picture. Let me know if that help.

Comment: Are the feature classes in the same projection? Could you share a screen cap of the tool window filled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The class feature (purple layer) didn't have a shape_area attribute and the tabulate intersection tool uses the shape_area to find the percentage of the overlapped areas. That's why everything was so off.